# Randomly changing NAs and/or factor level to other factor levels in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data-frame in which a column is a categorical variable "group" with 3 levels: "A", "B", "Unknown" and it also has NAs.

I want to take all the "Unknown" and NAs and randomly assign half to "A" and half to "B". I tried using `mutate()` and `replace()` functions in **dplyr** but can't think of how to randomly assign them equally to either group.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ...

```
replacements = sample ( c ( 'A', 'B' ), number_wanted, replace = TRUE )
```

... should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It'd be useful to have a [reproducible example (reprex)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

the `data.table` package offers a concise solution.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df) # make your data.frame into a data.table

# filter for rows where your grouping variable is NA or equals "Unknown" then randomly select A or B. .N is a special data.table character representing the number of rows in the selection

df[is.na(group_var) | group_var == "Unknown", group_var := sample(c("A", "B"), .N)]
```